# Rails 4 - query on association count is greater than an attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like "Find all Books where book.pages.count < books.max_pages".

So the models are:

```
class Book
  has_many :pages
end

class Page
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I know I can find books w/ a set number of pages. eg:

```
# Get books w/ < 5 pages.
Book.joins(:pages).group("books.id").having("count(pages.id) < ?", 5)
```

Is there a good way to do this with a dynamic page count? eg:

```
Book.joins(:pages).group("books.id").select(.having("count(pages.id) <= book.max_pages")
```

If not I can always just store something inside the Book model (eg `book.is_full = false` until a save causes it to be full), but this is a bit less flexible if max_pages gets updated.

Comment: What is `max_pages` in this `book.max_pages` ?

Comment: Where is `max_pages` coming from? Is it an instance or a class method/attribute you're trying to reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use counter_cache!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  4.1.2.3 :counter_cache

Comment: Thanks! I added an edit that shows an example of this in case someone else stumbles across the post.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a scope like this:

```
def self.page_count_under(amount)
  joins(:pages)
    .group('books.id')
    .having('COUNT(pages.id) < ?', amount)
end
```

**UPDATE**

This should work if `max_pages` is an attribute of the `Book` model.

```
def self.page_count_under_max
  joins(:pages)
    .group('books.id')
    .having('COUNT(pages.id) < books.max_pages')
end
```

Comment: I need the amount to be defined on by the book model, so it would change for each book, not just for one query, and I'd like to find all books like this at once.

Comment: Worth mentioning that grouping only on the books.id will work only on some databases.

Comment: Oh it might be marginally more efficient in some databases to use "count(pages.book_id) < ..." as table access can be avoided in favour of just accessing the index on the book_id column.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that issue so thanks for bringing it up. And is there really that much of a performance impact when using `books.id` as opposed to `pages.book_id`, or is it pretty negligable? I will try to keep those thoughts in mind for future reference.

Comment: I appreciate the updated response. I haven't tested it because I ended up learning enouhg about counter caches to make them work and it really simplified things.

Comment: I think `.group(:id)` is better instead of `.group('books.id')`